# Find renamed command from original command

Tags: tcl

Is there any tcl function/proc/api with which I can get all renamed commands?

I mean:

Suppose someone writes below statement somewhere in included files:

```
rename -force command tmp_command
```

After this line, there is no command for 'command', instead, 'tmp_command' is the new command.

How can I get renamed command, 'tmp_command' given that I have only 'command' name where I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl does not remember the renames that it does for you, but you can craft your own by tracing calls to `rename` (on the leave side so that you can track only successful calls):

```
trace add execution rename leave rememberRename
proc rememberRename {cmd code args} { # see the docs for the full list of callback arguments
    if {$code == 0} {
        lappend ::renames [lrange $cmd 1 end]
    }
}

# demo code
proc foo x y
rename foo bar
rename bar grill
rename grill foo
puts $renames
# {foo bar} {bar grill} {grill foo}
```

Caveat: this does not track all *deletions* of commands.

Comment: Traditionally, you did this by overriding `rename`, but traces are more elegant and easier.